# Update QListWidget to add user input

Tags: python, qt, pyside6

I add custom list items to the QListWidget.
The custom list item has a QFormLayout where I initially add the title, and a loading gif.
When a script requires input, a function 'create_input_form' adds new rows to the form layout including a QLable, a QLineEdit, and two QPushButtons (Ok and Cancel).

I then attempt to get user input within the QListWidget because the form now has the input option.

My problem is that the input section added to the form layout only gets added after all the list items have been added to the QListWidget, and therefore the new input section is behind the existing list items.

I call the create_input_form when I require input in my MainWindow class. The funcitonality of what I am doing is working, it is only the issue with updating the QListWidget after I called create_input_form, and then after one of the buttons is clcked and those rows in the form layout are removed

Is there a way to get the QListWidget to refresh. I have tried repaint() and update(), but maybe I am doing it incorrectly.

Here is the CustomListItem class

```
class CustomListItem(QWidget):

    def __init__(
            self, 
            item_id):
        super().__init__()
        self.item_id = item_id # Unique identifier for the list item
        self.input_script_name = ""
        self.input_script_request = ""
        
        # # Create base layout
        self.layout_base = QVBoxLayout(self)
        
        
        self.layout_script = QHBoxLayout()
                


        
        self.layout_form = QFormLayout()
        
        self.scriptLabel = QLabel(self.script_name)
        
        self.layout_script.addWidget(self.scriptLabel)
        

        # Placeholder for a progress icon or additional status label
        self.statusLabel = QLabel(self)
        movie = QMovie(os.path.abspath(u"./Images/loadgif(1).gif"))
        self.statusLabel.setMovie(movie)
        movie.start()
        
        
        # add label and status label to HBox
        self.layout_script.addWidget(self.statusLabel)
        
        # add HBox to form 
        self.layout_form.addRow(self.layout_script)
        
        self.layout_base.addLayout(self.layout_form)
        
        self.setLayout(self.layout_base)
    
    # Definition to create a user input under the relevant script list item when that list item requires input
    def create_input_form(self, input_script_request):

        self.input_script_request = input_script_request
        
        
        # Input fields
        self.scriptInputRequest = QLabel(self.input_script_request)
        
        self.scriptInputField = QLineEdit() # create line edit for user input
        
        # Create a lineedit based on whether the input is for a password or not
        if 'password' in self.input_script_request:
            self.scriptInputField.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)   # set echomode to password

        # add label and status label to form row
        self.layout_form.addRow(self.scriptInputRequest)
        self.layout_form.addRow(self.scriptInputField)
        
        # Buttons
        self.okButton = QPushButton("Ok")   # create ok button
        self.cancelButton = QPushButton("Cancel")   # create cancel button

        # add buttons to form row
        self.layout_form.addRow(self.okButton, self.cancelButton)
        
        # On clicked methods connect
        self.okButton.clicked.connect(self.ok_clicked)
        self.cancelButton.clicked.connect(self.cancel_clicked)

    # Called when ok button is clicked
    def ok_clicked(self):
        self.layout_form.removeRow(3)
        self.layout_form.removeRow(2)
        self.layout_form.removeRow(1)
        
        
    # Called when cancel button is clicked
    def cancel_clicked(self):
        
        self.layout_form.removeRow(3)
        self.layout_form.removeRow(2)
        self.layout_form.removeRow(1)
```

Here is the GUI output:

[image: GUI image of QListWidget]

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).